# How to merge 3 map of maps effectively in java

Tags: java

Merge below 3 maps if values exist then replace and if the value is new then add that value, for example :-

I have a Map1 as :-

```
{
     BMW = {
        SIZE=1, 
        SPEED=60
    }, 
     AUDI = {
        SIZE=5, 
        SPEED=21
    },
     SEAT= {
        SPEED=15
     }
}
```

And a Map2 as :-

```
{
         Suzuki = {
            WHEELS_SIZE=2, 
            DOORS=3
        }, 
         AUDI = {
            WHEELS_SIZE=5,
            SIZE=4,
            DOORS=5
        },
         SEAT= {
            DOORS=4
         }
    }
```

And Map3 as :-

```
{
         
         TOYOTA = {
            WHEELS_SIZE=5, 
            DOORS=5
        },
         BMW= {
            SIZE=10
         }
    }
```

I have a requirement to merge all 3 above so, that final map looks like

```
{
         BMW = {
            SIZE=10, 
            SPEED=60
        }, 
         AUDI = {
            SIZE=4, 
            SPEED=21,
            WHEELS_SIZE=5, 
            DOORS=5
        },
         SEAT= {
            SPEED=15,
            DOORS=4
         },
         Suzuki = {
            WHEELS_SIZE=2, 
            DOORS=3
        },
        TOYOTA = {
            WHEELS_SIZE=5, 
            DOORS=5
        },
    }
```

Could someone please suggest an optimized way to achieve this ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use nested maps when you could use classes...

Comment: "Also, please assume that all the maps here are immutable" - if you'd provide a [mcve] instead of just pseudo-JSON, we wouldn't need to assume anything.

Comment: @
Jon Skeet I have written that because the nested maps above are of type as  `Map` which is immutable. If i have to make those mergable then do i need to convert them to `HashMap`

Comment: In worst condition, i will convert them to HashMap

Comment: I have edited the description, it is not necessary

Comment: Collect all top-level keys from all maps, then iterate over this keyset and combine the values obtained sequentially from map1,map2 & map3

Comment: Thanks @ Nikolai Shevchenko. Could you please share any snippet

Comment: Using Map here is not well designed. Enum or Classes will be far better ways, flexible choices. Use your input maps to create a pool of living objects if you need to make some computations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a naïve implementation:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Map<String, Integer> BMW1 = new HashMap<>();
        BMW1.put("SIZE", 1);
        BMW1.put("SPEED", 60);
        Map<String, Integer> AUDI1 = new HashMap<>();
        AUDI1.put("SIZE", 5);
        AUDI1.put("SPEED", 21);
        Map<String, Integer> SEAT1 = new HashMap<>();
        SEAT1.put("SPEED", 15);
        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> one =
                Map.of("BMW", BMW1, "AUDI", AUDI1, "SEAT", SEAT1);

        Map<String, Integer> SUZUKI2 = new HashMap<>();
        SUZUKI2.put("WHEEL_SIZE", 2);
        SUZUKI2.put("DOORS", 3);
        Map<String, Integer> AUDI2 = new HashMap<>();
        AUDI2.put("WHEELS_SIZE", 5);
        AUDI2.put("SIZE", 4);
        AUDI2.put("DOORS", 5);
        Map<String, Integer> SEAT2 = new HashMap<>();
        SEAT2.put("DOORS", 4);
        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> two =
                Map.of("SUZUKI", SUZUKI2, "AUDI", AUDI2, "SEAT", SEAT2);

        Map<String, Integer> TOYOTA3 = new HashMap<>();
        TOYOTA3.put("WHEEL_SIZE", 5);
        TOYOTA3.put("DOORS", 5);
        Map<String, Integer> BMW3 = new HashMap<>();
        BMW3.put("SIZE", 10);
        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> three =
                Map.of("TOYOTA", TOYOTA3, "BMW", BMW3);

        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>[] maps = new Map[]{ one, two, three };
        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> mergedMaps = mergeMaps(maps);

        printMap(mergedMaps);
    }

    public static Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> mergeMaps(Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>[] maps) {
        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> mergedMap = new HashMap<>();

        for(Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> map : maps) {
            for(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                if(mergedMap.containsKey(entry.getKey())){
                    Map<String, Integer> mergedCarStats = mergedMap.get(entry.getKey());
                    Map<String, Integer> carStats = entry.getValue();

                    mergedCarStats.putAll(carStats);
                } else {
                    mergedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            }
        }

        return mergedMap;
    }

    public static void printMap(Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> car) {
        System.out.println("{");
        for(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Integer>> entry: car.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("  %s = {", entry.getKey()));
            printStats(entry.getValue());
            System.out.println("  },");
        }
        System.out.println("}");
    }

    public static void printStats(Map<String, Integer> stats) {
        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : stats.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("    '%s': %d,", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        }
    }
```

If you run it you will get this output:

```
{
  SUZUKI = {
    'WHEEL_SIZE': 2,
    'DOORS': 3,
  },
  SEAT = {
    'SPEED': 15,
    'DOORS': 4,
  },
  AUDI = {
    'SPEED': 21,
    'DOORS': 5,
    'SIZE': 4,
    'WHEELS_SIZE': 5,
  },
  TOYOTA = {
    'WHEEL_SIZE': 5,
    'DOORS': 5,
  },
  BMW = {
    'SPEED': 60,
    'SIZE': 10,
  },
}
```

Which is what you asked for. There are a few things to consider though. Using loops this way is inefficient because the [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) is going to be O(n^2) as there are 2 for loops. There are built in functions for [merging maps](https://www.baeldung.com/java-merge-maps) since Java 8 which could be worth exploring.

Answer (score 0):

Merge the three maps using java8

```
Map<String,  Map<String, Integer>> resultMap = Stream.of(map1, map2, map3)
            .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    e -> new HashMap<String,Integer>(e.getValue()),
                    (key, value) -> {key.putAll(value); return key;}
            ));
```

Output:

{SEAT={SPEED=15, DOORS=4}, TOYOTA={WHEELS_SIZE=5, DOORS=5}, Suzuki={WHEELS_SIZE=2, DOORS=3}, AUDI={SPEED=21, WHEELS_SIZE=5, DOORS=5, SIZE=4}, BMW={SPEED=60, SIZE=10}}